# Porqué no se puede abrir el archivo origen "iostream"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

es mi primera vez en visual studio y el intellisense se queja de la inexistencia de "iostream"

[image]

¿Tengo que instalarlo? Y si sí, ¿dónde lo instalo?

Comment: En vez de una captura de pantalla de un trozo del código, publica todo tu código. Con eso solo que has subido es imposible darte una solución.

Comment: @SuperG280 el código no es el problema, el problema es la inexistencia del archivo "iostream", no pido ayuda con la función primaria

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero ayúdanos a responder preguntas cumplan con lo definido en el [help], especificamente [ask], te sugerimos revisa [ask], Saludos.

Comment: mmmmmmmm intenta esto si puedes, cierra todo y en el proyecto que creaste click derecho y sale una opciones del editor ue4, dale click para generar... *generate visual studio proyect fies*

Comment: Mira si te deja compilar el proyecto. Si si te deja compilarlo entonces es un error del intelisence. Puede ser un bug. Si no te deja compilarlo es una mala instalacion de visual studio, y te recomendaria reinstalarlo

Comment: yo tambien tengo el mismo problema en visual studio y me parece que
es un problema de directorios y porsupuesto donde estan ubicados los
archivos de nuestra librearia por lo menos la que estamos usando en el poryecto.

Answer (score 0):

En Windows hay que instalar el compilador gcc/g++ que ya contendría esa y otras librerías.

El vscode recomienda MSYS2 (https://www.msys2.org/) donde tendrás que seguir las instrucciones para descargar el compilador una vez instalado `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`

Luego habría que añadir la ruta, normalmente `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`, en la configuración del IntelliSense dentro del vscode (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Answer (score -2):

hasta donde me acuerdo te falta colocar lo siguiente antes del iostream

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

esa es una de las macanas del visual studio

Comment: Ya había intentado eso, pero no funcionó

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero ayúdanos a responder preguntas cumplan con lo definido en el [help], especificamente [ask], te sugerimos revisa [ask], Saludos.